# On create error, should I render `new` or redirect to `new`?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Suppose  I have something like this:

```
def new
  @user = User.new
end
def create
  @user = User.create(params[:user])
  if @user.save
    flash[:notice] = 'User created'
    redirect_to :action => 'list'
  else
    flash[:error] = 'Some error here!'
    render 'new'
  end
end
```

I think the code is clear.
The problem here is, when the `@user` object is not saved successfully, should I render `new` (as above) or should redirect to `new`?

I know if redirect to `new` the data input by the user is lost, but if I render `new`, the URL will be `/users/create` instead of `/users/new` (which is ugly!).

Comment: I don't agree with the downvoting of this question. Could someone justify it?

Comment: Totally irrational downvoting of the question i must say! :) upvoted.

Answer (score 2):

You are correct in not using `redirect`. Redirect is loading an entirely new resource.

`render` however will keep your session data fresh, and depending on how your form is set up, *should* repopulate whatever data was inputted.

You mention:

*I know if redirect to new the data input by the user is lost, but if I render new, the URL will be /users/create instead of /users/new (which is ugly!).*

No, this is not true. If you say `render 'new'`, it will go to the url `users/new` not create. Create as an action only handles `POST` requests to your controller, and generally never has a view associated with it. It will instead refer to the `new` action to handle any errors and displaying of forms.

The create action has this in common with the `update` action which does the same thing by handling only `PUT` requests, but refers to the `edit` action to handle the displaying of views.

Comment: I know this is 3 years old, but I'm having the same issue and `render :new` does not give us the correct URL. It does preserve the form data and show the error messages, but the URL is `/users` instead of `/users/new`. I'd sure love to have this answered if anyone can shed some light.

Comment: @aviemet same here. Did you ever find an answer to this?

Comment: @aviemet I'm also interested, the same issue.

Comment: I know this question is 10 years old, but I am having this URL mismatch issue too, lol.  This post does a fine job explaining what's happening, and offers a solution: https://fullstackheroes.com/tutorials/rails/wrong-url-validation-error/

In short add this route: 

`resources :user, only: [:show, :edit]`
`put '/user/:id/edit', to: 'user#update', as: 'update_user'`

Then change your update resource form to be:
`<%= form_for @user, url: update_user_path(@user), method: :put do |f| %>`